# iis7 setting for a website that only serves static files, no cookies

Tags: iis-7

if I am setting up a seperate domain name to handle all static file serving, is there anything special I need to do in IIS7 so it doesn't serve cookies etc?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Knowing it could help providing more helpful answers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS doesn't serve anything on its own, it only serves pages requested by clients and/or does things if some server-side application requests it to do them.

If you disable scripting and execution support in your web site, ony static file types will be served (HTML, images, etc.).

Of course, even a static HTML page can do whatever it wants on the client (including setting cookies)... but you can't tell IIS something like "only serve HTML pages that don't contain any client side scripting".

Comment: how about turning off modules?

Comment: I'm talking about client-side scripting. There's no way to turn **that** off: if you put a script in a HTML page, it will get executed (unless the client browser disables scripting itself, of course).

Answer (score 0):

In IIS manager, under session state you have the option to modify the way IIS handle cookies. I did not make test yet.